# Wi-Fi Direct in Android JellyBean

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct

I wish to enable the wifi direct in android jelly bean. But the logcat messgaes shows the below error message.

E/WifiHW  ( 2460): Unable to open connection to supplicant on "/data/misc/wifi/sockets/p2p0": No such file or directory

I googled to find out the exact reason for this message.But could not find any.

Could anyone please share why this error occuring?

Comment: It might be useful to include the source code for your application where you're trying to call this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `wpa_supplicant` on your device is built without P2P support.
Check if `CONFIG_P2P` is enabled in it's `android.config` file.

Comment: I am manually copying wpa_supplicant binary to the /system/bin folder.Could you please tell me the steps to enable the building of wpa_supplicant with NL80211?

Comment: How about `CONFIG_DRIVER_NL80211=y` in the same file, `android.config`? I recommend you checking by yourself first, before asking. Also, if my answer covers your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Andrejs Cainikovs : Thanks for the reply!! Now i am facing an issue in ICS. I am getting Group formation timed out when my device acts as group owner and connection fails.. Can you please look it for me. Thank you